# Passing reference of component to its ChildContent components

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

To add some context, I'm trying to create a Dropdown `select` Blazor component. I've managed to create a concept of this entirely with CSS, `@onclick`, and `@onfocusout`.

I'm trying to pass a reference of the `DropDown` component to its children, `DropDownItem`. The only way I know how to achieve this, is by using the `@ref` and passing it as a parameter to the `DropDownItem` component.

```html
<DropDown @ref="DropDownReference">
    <DropDownItem ParentDropDown=@DropDownReference>Hello</DropDownItem>
    <DropDownItem ParentDropDown=@DropDownReference>World</DropDownItem>
</DropDown>
```

There has to be a cleaner approach here that does not require manually passing the reference down to each child instance. I suppose I could use `CascadingValue` but that will still require me to store the `DropDown` reference.

**I'm trying to notify `DropDown` parent when a click event occurs in `DropDownItem`. This will signal the parent to changes it selected value - as it would traditionally work in a `select`.**

Comment: `CascadingValue` is the way to do it.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a reference of `DropDown` using `CascadingValue` without the need to store the `DropDown` reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do it using `CascadingValue`. The `DropDownItem` component will accept a `[CascadingParameter]` of type `DropDown`. There is nothing wrong in doing that, this is how it's done in most (if not all) component libraries.

DropDown.razor

```
<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed="true">
    @* Dropdown code *@
    <div class="dropdown">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    private string selectedItem;

    public void SelectItem(string item)
    {
        selectedItem = item;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

DropDownItem.razor

```
@* Dropdown item code *@
<div class="dropdown-item" @onclick="OnItemClick">...</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public DropDown ParentDropDown { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Name { get; set; }

    private void OnItemClick()
    {
        ParentDropDown.SelectItem(Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<DropDown>
    <DropDownItem Name="Hello">Hello</DropDownItem>
    <DropDownItem Name="World">World</DropDownItem>
</DropDown>
```